# How to compare 2 float in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, x87

i´, completely novice in assembly.
I want to compare two variables (float) and jump correctly to the right function;
Its a Pong game
Its written in FASM

```
 ;The right pad
  P0x dd  0.9  ;
  P0y dd  0.05 ;
  P1x dd  0.95 ;
  P1y dd  -0.25 ;

 ;The left pad
  P0x2 dd -0.9
  P0y2 dd  0.05
  P1x2 dd -0.95
  P1y2 dd - 0.25

B0x GLfloat  0.01 ; Its the ball coordinate
...
BvelX GLfloat 0.02 ;Its the velocity that the ball move in x
...
```

I want that: if the ball position is the same or more then the Pad position, then invert the velocity.
What i do:

```
;right
 fld [B0x]
 fld [P0x]
 fcomip st1
 jge .changexEsq

 ;left
 fld [B0x]
 fld [P0x2]
 fcomip st1
 jle .changexDir

 ;Up
 fld [B0y]
 fld [TelaComecoY]
 fcomip st1
 jge .changeyBaixo

 ;Down
 fld [B0y]
 fld  [TelaFimY]
 fcomip st1
 jge .changeyBaixo

  ....
.changexEsq:
mov edi,-0.02
mov [BvelX],edi
jmp .main
    ret

.changexDir:
mov edi, 0.02
mov [BvelX],edi
jmp .main
    ret

.changeyBaixo:
mov edi,-0.02
mov [BvelY],edi
jmp .main
    ret

.changeyCima:
mov edi,-0.02
mov [BvelY],edi
jmp .main
    ret
```

But the comparation is doing nothing ! How could i compare those variables and jump correctly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FCOM` and company (FCOMP, FCOMPP, FICOM, FICOMP) put results in the floating point status word, *not* in the main CPU flags register. You can use `fstsw` to store the floating point status word somewhere you can get at it and act on its contents (e.g., to store to AX, you use `FSTSW AX`).

Note that this is somewhat roundabout. In some cases, you may want to consider treating the numbers as if they were integers -- IEEE 754 was carefully designed so that integer comparisons for ordering mostly yield correct results for floating point numbers.

Comment: Use `sahf` (Store AH into FLAGS) after `fstsw`.  Or use `fcomip` to compare into FLAGS in the first place (new instruction on P6 CPUs). See also http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html.   Or use SSE `ucomiss` instead of legacy x87 at all.  See also [x86 assembler: floating point compare](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7057501)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you want `JAE`/`JBE`, not `JLE`/`JGE`, when using `FCOMIP` to compare the floats with EFLAGS (ZF, PF and CF).