# x86 assembler: floating point compare

Tags: x86, floating-point, compare, assembly, gnu-assembler

As part of a compiler project I have to write GNU assembler code for x86 to compare floating point values. I have tried to find resources on how to do this online and from what I understand it works like this:

Assuming the two values I want to compare are the only values on the floating point stack, then the `fcomi` instruction will compare the values and set the CPU-flags so that the `je`, `jne`, `jl`, ... instructions can be used.

I'm asking because this only works sometimes. For example:

```
.section    .data
msg:    .ascii "Hallo\n\0"
f1:     .float 10.0
f2:     .float 9.0

.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    flds f1
    flds f2
    fcomi
    jg leb
    pushl $msg
    call printf
    addl $4, %esp
leb:
    pushl $0
    call exit
```

will not print "Hallo" even though I think it should, and if you switch f1 and f2 it still won't which is a logical contradiction. `je` and `jne` however seem to work fine.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: does the fcomip pop only one value or does it pop both?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

TL:DR: **Use above / below conditions (like for unsigned integer) to test the result of compares**.

For various [historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188286/why-do-x86-fp-compares-set-cf-like-unsigned-integers-instead-of-using-signed-co) (mapping [from FP status word to FLAGS via `fcom` / `fstsw` / `sahf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227582/fcom-floating-point-comparison-fails) which [`fcomi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fcomi:fcomip:fucomi:fucomip) (new in PPro) matches), FP compares set CF, not OF / SF.  See also http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap7.htm

Modern SSE/SSE2 scalar compares into FLAGS [follow this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188286/why-do-x86-fp-compares-set-cf-like-unsigned-integers-instead-of-using-signed-co), with [u]`comiss` / `sd`.  (Unlike SIMD compares, which have a predicate as part of the instruction, as an immediate, since they only produce a single all-zeros / all-ones result for each element, not a set of FLAGS.)

---

This is all coming from Volume 2 of  [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/).

`FCOMI` sets only some of the flags that `CMP` does. Your code has `%st(0) == 9` and `%st(1) == 10`. (Since it's a stack they're loaded onto), referring to the table on page 3-348 in Volume 2A you can see that this is the case "ST0 < ST(i)", so it will clear ZF and PF and set CF. Meanwhile on pg. 3-544 Vol. 2A you can read that `JG` means "Jump short if greater (ZF=0 and SF=OF)". In other words it's testing the sign, overflow and zero flags, but `FCOMI` doesn't set sign or overflow!

Depending on which conditions you wish to jump, you should look at the possible comparison results and decide when you want to jump.

```
+--------------------+---+---+---+
| Comparison results | Z | P | C |
+--------------------+---+---+---+
| ST0 > ST(i)        | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ST0 < ST(i)        | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| ST0 = ST(i)        | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| unordered          | 1 | 1 | 1 |  one or both operands were NaN.
+--------------------+---+---+---+
```

I've made this small table to make it easier to figure out:

```
+--------------+---+---+-----+------------------------------------+
| Test         | Z | C | Jcc | Notes                              |
+--------------+---+---+-----+------------------------------------+
| ST0 < ST(i)  | X | 1 | JB  | ZF will never be set when CF = 1   |
| ST0 <= ST(i) | 1 | 1 | JBE | Either ZF or CF is ok              |
| ST0 == ST(i) | 1 | X | JE  | CF will never be set in this case  |
| ST0 != ST(i) | 0 | X | JNE |                                    |
| ST0 >= ST(i) | X | 0 | JAE | As long as CF is clear we are good |
| ST0 > ST(i)  | 0 | 0 | JA  | Both CF and ZF must be clear       |
+--------------+---+---+-----+------------------------------------+
Legend: X: don't care, 0: clear, 1: set
```

In other words the condition codes match those for using unsigned comparisons. The same goes if you're using `FMOVcc`.

If either (or both) operand to `fcomi` is NaN, it sets `ZF=1 PF=1 CF=1`.  (FP compares have 4 possible results: `>`, `<`, `==`, or unordered).  If you care what your code does with NaNs, you may need an extra `jp` or `jnp`.  But not always: for example, `ja` is only true if CF=0 and ZF=0, so it will be not-taken in the unordered case.  If you want the unordered case to take the same execution path as below or equal, then `ja` is all you need.

---

Here you should use `JA` if you want it to print (ie. `if (!(f2 > f1)) { puts("hello"); }`) and `JBE` if you don't (corresponds to `if (!(f2 <= f1)) { puts("hello"); }`). (Note this might be a little confusing due to the fact that we only print if we don't jump).

---

Regarding your second question: by default `fcomi` doesn't pop anything. You want its close cousin `fcomip` which pops `%st0`. You should always clear the fpu register stack after usage, so all in all your program ends up like this assuming you want the message printed:

```
.section    .rodata
msg:    .ascii "Hallo\n\0"
f1:     .float 10.0
f2:     .float 9.0 

.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    flds   f1
    flds   f2
    fcomip
    fstp   %st(0) # to clear stack
    ja     leb # won't jump, jbe will
    pushl  $msg
    call   printf
    addl   $4, %esp
leb:
    pushl  $0
    call   exit
```

Comment: Very impressive answer.  Outstanding. One minor comment: the opposite of `ja` is `jbe`, not `jb`.

Comment: @Ray Toal: You are absolutely right. Even though it won't make any difference in this case I changed the example since it makes more sense that way.