# Branch based on the results of vcmpsd

Tags: assembly, nasm, sse, avx

Here is a small segment of NASM code:

```
vpxor xmm3,xmm3,xmm3
vmovsd xmm0,[rdi+rcx]
vmovsd xmm1,[rsi+rcx]
vsubsd xmm2,xmm0,xmm1
vcmpsd xmm4,xmm2,xmm3,0
je c_this

c_not_this:
mov rax,0
c_this:
mov rax,0
```

In the first two lines I move two numbers (doubles) to compare into xmm0 and xmm1.  In this case, they are equal.  Next I subtract them, and the result in xmm2 is zero.  Finally, I compare the results of the subtraction to zero, and I expect xmm4 to be zero, but it's not:

```
(gdb) p $xmm4.v2_double
$3 = {-nan(0xfffffffffffff), 0}
```

So the result of the comparison -- in xmm4 -- is -nan(0xfffffffffffff).  At the branch statement it does not jump to c_this, so the -nan is not seen as zero.

As a more general question, how do I branch on the results of vcmpsd?  The instruction apparently doesn't affect flags.  There is surprisingly little information on this on the internet.

Comment: Why do you want to use `vcmpsd` for scalar compare+branch?  Do you also want the 1-element mask for something else as well?  If so, use `movmskpd` and `test` the low bit of the mask. If you just want to compare/branch on two `double`s, use `ucomisd` or `comisd` to set integer FLAGS, like compilers do.  (https://godbolt.org/ and look at compiler output for `if (d1 == d2) dummy = 0;` - any time you wonder what the normal way to do something simple is, ask a compiler.)

Comment: duplicate for the XY-problem of comparing `double`s: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558200/what-is-the-best-way-to-perform-branching-using-intel-sse (obviously using AVX `vucomisd` instead of SSE `ucomisd` if the surrounding code is AVX.)