# Fastest way to set __m256 value to all ONE bits

Tags: bit-manipulation, intrinsics, avx, avx2

How can I set a value of 1 to all bits in an `__m256` value?
Using either AVX or AVX2 intrinsics?

To get all zeros, you can use `_mm256_setzero_si256()`.

To get all ones, I'm currently using `_mm256_set1_epi64x(-1)`, but I suspect that this is slower than the all-zero case. Is there memory access or Scalar/SSE/AVX switching involved here?

And I can't seem to find a simple bitwise NOT operation in AVX?
If that was available, I could simply use the setzero, followed by a vector NOT.

Comment: In former times, people used `pcmpeqd xmm0, xmm0` for that, presumably there is an equivalent operation in AVX{2}?

Comment: @njuffa `vpcmpeqd` in AVX2. Clang seems to optimize the `_mm256_set1_epi64x(-1);` to that, the same as `_mm256_cmpeq_epi64(_mm256_setzero_si256(), _mm256_setzero_si256());`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35085059/555045

Comment: Have a look at section 13.8 *Generating constants* in [Agner Fog's An optimization guide for x86 platforms](https://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See also [Set all bits in CPU register to 1 efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105164/set-all-bits-in-cpu-register-to-1-efficiently/45113467#45113467) which covers AVX, AVX2, and AVX512 zmm and k (mask) registers.

---

You obviously didn't even look at the asm output, which is trivial to do:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
__m256i all_ones(void) { return _mm256_set1_epi64x(-1); }
```

[compiles to](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOQCse5dq3qhUAUgBMAIRmzyAZ2ydURAg2rZ6mAMLp2AVwC29EAFYA7OR2YAMgXrYAcqYBG2UiABs5AA7oSsSa9AbGZpY2gcEaDI7Obiae3n4qanH0TESspEThpubWyqrY6qHZuUQJrh5evso5eQWRxUpN1U61yfU%2BAJTK6EakqFwA5DIAzE6oxjgA1JKTegQmJk5EpE4AdEhLuJIADACCR8cA%2Bucm0hY%2BBPMc7OcM2EoQAG7oBJh9i1ay81I2CIw3o8yu11u5xURG452w/gIPl4AA8IABabh9JYAyRWAAiZzOl0hPge7CeLyU538b0%2B31%2BePkJ3mrPBVxuZPoYiUi0m%2BPBa055zY7WCwtpEEFpOhwLhCIIk2kGKx82xk2ZxzZgOBoPm3PoShxRIJbLGA3YIDGFjG5HMY0OtvQVr0CgU8yUQxG2EW0km3FtRCtjr6AwA1iBeFZtgAOCwATkOhysMaVMfjMe4NktY14tpMlkOduDTqttqUICLQYd5vIcFgKAwJkRnAoVAgTZb9WA3EO3HINAI7CIXgrEHcJfI7icuQAnlaA%2BQmyYdEQAPL0djzmvkHAmMTATiTwhA8rvV6T7AospGEcL20bVST9gEdykOcGHD38ibVb3gZ0IwLAcFwfCCCAkwiAeaBunIIivhWkADOg/iZBWYzovuIx7PySCsEoADuqjsPM6IoqgpHtJgSz4sA9BGNw3CkQA6o8pE0OepDuEE2DovhJikWukzlqU5RaBAdgtOY/Z2DUSQpMIMQhAwUmKUEyn0HJdTeP26RlJklTNIYhTCHpYlZB0Wk9DpjRVKpumWV08n1FigzDKMPAWlaNrFjuzpjCiMY%2BOiyLzMAqAUb22xMRA%2BDEGQvr%2BuQ8wGM2Q5eIlky/K6cgKIGJahuQSDYKwODeBAXm5vmha%2BY65D%2BeWlY/gV4aRtGcaJsmqbSOmmbZlawm1aWYz5TWAz1gg8AQI26Bpa2lDUJ26XeLMB4WEmA5DiOpBjhOO7TtypDbouy6rhuW7Htg%2B7iEeO4nvpBDnuhdVXjed5jIuj45nVL5vh%2BWDjIuv4Fh9taAcwbBHmBQj9qI4gwblcG/YhFX1ahoToZhuSoDh%2BJ4YRxGCZMpHkZRRDUfydEMUx6KsRS7GcdxKh8UoJgiRkoTaLo9m2LoVkKf2SmZDzQuhPzLklBzDCGfkxmRLpokGY5iTaaZHQ8%2B0VTizpAyeu5oGVT59p1f5gXBaFq3iPMFjbIctvzLFhAkKQiX9ils1di7Uyqjl8hyKNIatRY0jRbwhzxvG0jcD4Vi9twqYiFaebkAW61DfVZbKE11YhnWiDTWgHvLQtHZF62aBwz2SZFoOw6jtQe11Qdc7fqdjDndudV7get1dwQp4aE9l7Xqgt6Aw%2BjBPjuv3vkdn7jz%2BWwgwGAEMBDIE8PwQjSFB8NSIjijI/AyHowwmNYTjNFKGImCzm%2B3zAD66JCSTFHolRNFU4xLFseiHFeEzXi/F2YPXEpJOW0leYOCcqrQW6lhYQLUrEMWMDrKmUVhUdWiCFZSwslrVBAtbJGQiJAzWeRtaeTct6ShOYjaTlNkFEKvB5iW2APMKKdtDgOzis7V2yVUqe0StIbKsFZAB3NAMYqpV6ioxzMnVORZjbDUalWFq5AIzB1DuHSO0dY59gTjmQaSiM4jWamNSq0hbTGIamYwO5BOLBC0LwIAA) with GCC and clang with any `-march` that includes AVX2

```
    vpcmpeqd        ymm0, ymm0, ymm0
    ret
```

To get a `__m256` (not `__m256i`) you can just cast the result:

```
  __m256 nans = _mm256_castsi256_ps( _mm256_set1_epi32(-1) );
```

**Without AVX2, a possible option is [`vcmptrueps dst, ymm0,ymm0`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpps)** preferably with a cold register for the input to mitigate the false dependency.

Recent clang (5.0 and later) does xor-zero a vector then `vcmpps` with a TRUE predicate if AVX2 isn't available.  Older clang makes a 128bit all-ones with `vpcmpeqd xmm` and uses `vinsertf128`.  GCC loads from memory, even modern GCC 10.1 with `-march=sandybridge`.

---

As described by the vector section of [Agner Fog's optimizing assembly guide](http://agner.org/optimize/), generating constants on the fly this way is cheap.  It still takes a vector execution unit to generate the all-ones ([unlike `_mm_setzero`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/which-is-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/33668295#33668295)), but it's better than any possible two-instruction sequence, and usually better than a load.  See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

Compilers don't like to [generate more complex constants on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35085059/555045), even ones that could be generated from all-ones with a simple shift.  Even if you try, by writing `__m128i float_signbit_mask = _mm_srli_epi32(_mm_set1_epi16(-1), 1)`, compilers typically do constant-propagation and put the vector in memory.  This lets them fold it into a memory operand when used later in cases where there's no loop to hoist the constant out of.

---

> And I can't seem to find a simple bitwise NOT operation in AVX?

You do that by XORing with all-ones with `vxorps` (`_mm256_xor_ps`).  Unfortunately SSE/AVX don't provide a way to do a NOT without a vector constant.

---

**FP vs Integer instructions and bypass delay**

Intel CPUs (at least Skylake) have a weird effect where the extra bypass latency between SIMD-integer and SIMD-FP still happens long after the uop producing the register has executed.  e.g. `vmulps ymm1, ymm2, ymm0` could have an extra cycle of latency for the `ymm2` -> `ymm1` critical path if `ymm0` was produced by `vpcmpeqd`.  And this lasts until the next context switch restores FP state if you don't otherwise overwrite `ymm0`.

This is not a problem for bitwise instructions like `vxorps` (even though the mnemonic has `ps`, it doesn't have bypass delay from FP or vec-int domains on Skylake, IIRC).

So normally it's safe to create a `set1(-1)` constant with an integer instruction because that's a NaN and you wouldn't normally use it with FP math instructions like mul or add.

Comment: You can also produce a NOT as follows: not_a = _mm256_andnot_ps(a, all_ones);

Comment: @ChipK: I seem to recall you doing the same thing recently, that's why I complained.  If that was a different user, then nvm.  Try to have your comment finished before you post it.  Accidents happen, but don't do it on purpose.  If I'm on SO, I'll often look at a comment notification right away when it pops up, so if necessary I can reply while the person is also still there.  Anyway, yes ANDN works, too, but then you have to remember which operand is the one that's NOTed, and it doesn't work as a load (only the non-memory operand can be NOTed; it's not commutative).

Comment: Anyway, thanks for pointing out ANDN.  But since it still requires a vector of all-ones, and has zero advantages over XOR, I don't think it's worth suggesting as an alternative to consider.  IDK if some people would find it more readable.  But for me, XOR with ones is immediately understandable.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to add a carriage return between my text and my code and it added the comment - simple mistake (difference between adding a comment and adding an answer).  BTW, I don't think it was me that you were pointing out priorly.

Comment: You link to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105164/set-all-bits-in-cpu-register-to-1-efficiently/45113467#45113467), which for the AVX/AVX2 case says "The AVX/AVX2 version of this [`pcmpeqd`] is also the best choice there", but what is the AVX (not AVX2) version of `pcmpeqd`? Then from there you link back here.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: With this question being tagged AVX2, it seems I didn't put too much effort into the AVX1 case.  The real answer being: look at compiler output and consider their choices.  That should probably get updated.

Comment: @PeterCordes re:"Compilers don't like to generate more complex constants on the fly, even ones that could be generated from all-ones with a simple shift" Working on it in LLVM. Its a bit more complicated than one might think but is on the horizon.