# AVX2 set __mm256d variable to all ones

Tags: c, vectorization, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I am trying to make a constant all binary ones __m256d variable. I saw the post [Fastest way to set __m256 value to all ONE bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469930/fastest-way-to-set-m256-value-to-all-one-bits) but it only handles the case of __m256i and __m256, not __m256d. Thank you for your help

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want 4 times `1.0` ? Because Intel generally doesn't care that much what bits mean when they're copied. Broadcasting 64 bits works the same for `long long` and `double`

Comment: The `__m256d` case is just a slightly different cast from the `__m256` case; I didn't think it was worth mentioning in my answer there because once you understand how/why the `__m256` version works, the `__m256d` version is straightforward.  `_mm256_cast*` intrinsics just reinterpret the bits of a vector, aka type-pun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fill the bits to one as you did and then cast it to the __m256d register:

```
__m256i a = _mm256_set1_epi64x(-1);
__m256d b = _mm256_castsi256_pd(a);
```

Or simply:

```
__m256d b = _mm256_castsi256_pd(_mm256_set1_epi64x(-1));
```