# SIMD (AVX): how to 'blend' floats via runtime-computed mask?

Tags: sse, simd, avx

How to conditionally keep `equal floats using AVX intrinsics?

I have

```
__m256 valA = .....;
__m256 valB = .....;

__m256 aIsB = _mm256_cmp_ps( valA, valB, _CMP_EQ_OS );
```

After getting such a mask I intended to use

```
__m256 zeros = _mm256_set1_ps(0.0f)
__m256 same = _mm256_blend_ps(valA, zeros, aIsB);//<--aIsB must actually be imm8
```

however `_mm256_blend_ps` requires mask to be a runtime compile constant.
Otherwise I would somehow need to cast `__m256` into `imm8`

Should I use some other function?

> Documentation:
>
> [_mm256_blend_ps](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_blend_ps&techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX&expand=449,744,449)
>
> [_mm256_cpm_ps](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_cmp_ps&techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX&expand=449,744,449,744)
>
> ["AVX compare" predicate variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988199/how-to-choose-avx-compare-predicate-variants)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instruction you were looking for is [`blendvps`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_blendv_ps&techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX), but if you want to have zero at every entry which does not fulfill the comparison, you can simply use [`andps`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_and_ps&techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX).

```
__m256 aIsB = _mm256_cmp_ps( valA, valB, _CMP_EQ_OS );
__m256 same = _mm256_and_ps( valA, aIsB);
```