# find nan in array of doubles using simd

Tags: c, nan, sse, simd, avx

This question is very similar to:

[SIMD instructions for floating point equality comparison (with NaN == NaN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951714)

Although that question focused on 128 bit vectors and had requirements about identifying +0 and -0.

I had a feeling I might be able to get this one myself but the intel intrinsics guide page seems to be down :/

My goal is to take an array of doubles and to return whether a NaN is present in the array. I am expecting that the majority of the time that there won't be one, and would like that route to have the best performance.

Initially I was going to do a comparison of 4 doubles to themselves, mirroring the non-SIMD approach for NaN detection (i.e. NaN only value where `a != a` is true). Something like:

```
data *double = ...
__m256d a, b;
int temp = 0;

//This bit would be in a loop over the array
//I'd probably put a sentinel in and loop over while !temp
a = _mm256_loadu_pd(data);
b = _mm256_cmp_pd(a, a, _CMP_NEQ_UQ);
temp = temp | _mm256_movemask_pd(b);
```

However, in some of the examples of comparison it looks like there is some sort of NaN detection already going on in addition to the comparison itself. I briefly thought, well if something like  `_CMP_EQ_UQ` will detect NaNs, I can just use that and then I can compare 4 doubles to 4 doubles and magically look at 8 doubles at once at the same time.

```
__m256d a, b, c;
a = _mm256_loadu_pd(data);
b = _mm256_loadu_pd(data+4);
c = _mm256_cmp_pd(a, b, _CMP_EQ_UQ);
```

At this point I realized I wasn't quite thinking straight because I might happen to compare a number to itself that is not a NaN (i.e. 3 == 3) and get a hit that way.

So my question is, is comparing 4 doubles to themselves (as done above) the best I can do or is there some other better approach to finding out whether my array has a NaN?

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to avoid this entirely by checking fenv status, or if not then cache block it and/or fold it into another pass over the same data, because it's very low computational intensity (work per byte loaded/stored), so it easily bottlenecks on memory bandwidth.  See below.

---

**The comparison predicate you're looking for is `_CMP_UNORD_Q` or `_CMP_ORD_Q`** to tell you that the comparison is unordered or ordered, i.e. that at least one of the operands is a NaN, or that both operands are non-NaN, respectively.  [What does ordered / unordered comparison mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627331/what-does-ordered-unordered-comparison-mean)

The asm docs for [`cmppd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmppd) list the predicates and have equal or better details than the intrinsics guide.

So yes, if you expect NaN to be rare and want to quickly scan through lots of non-NaN values, you can `vcmppd` two different vectors against each other.  If you cared about where the NaN was, you could do extra work to sort that out once you know that there is at least one in either of two input vectors.  (Like `_mm256_cmp_pd(a,a, _CMP_UNORD_Q)` to feed movemask + bitscan for lowest set bit.)

---

### OR or AND multiple compares per `movemask`

Like with other SSE/AVX search loops, you can also amortize the `movemask` cost by combining a few compare results with `_mm256_or_pd` (find any unordered) or `_mm256_and_pd` (check for all ordered).  E.g. **check a couple cache lines (4x `_mm256d` with 2x `_mm256_cmp_pd`) per movemask / test/branch.**  (glibc's asm `memchr` and `strlen` use this trick.)  Again, this optimizes for your common case where you expect no early-outs and have to scan the whole array.

**Also remember that it's totally fine to check the same element twice, so your cleanup can be simple**: a vector that loads up to the end of the array, potentially overlapping with elements you already checked.

```
// checks 4 vectors = 16 doubles
// non-zero means there was a NaN somewhere in p[0..15]
static inline
int any_nan_block(double *p) {
    __m256d a = _mm256_loadu_pd(p+0);
    __m256d abnan = _mm256_cmp_pd(a, _mm256_loadu_pd(p+ 4), _CMP_UNORD_Q);
    __m256d c = _mm256_loadu_pd(p+8);
    __m256d cdnan = _mm256_cmp_pd(c, _mm256_loadu_pd(p+12), _CMP_UNORD_Q);
    __m256d abcdnan = _mm256_or_pd(abnan, cdnan);
    return _mm256_movemask_pd(abcdnan);
}
// more aggressive ORing is possible but probably not needed
// especially if you expect any memory bottlenecks.
```

I wrote the C as if it were assembly, one instruction per source line.  (load / memory-source cmppd).  These 6 instructions are all single-uop in the fused-domain on modern CPUs, if using non-indexed addressing modes on Intel.  `test/jnz` as a `break` condition would bring it up to 7 uops.

In a loop, an `add reg, 16*8` pointer increment is another 1 uop, and `cmp / jne` as a loop condition is one more, bringing it up to 9 uops.  So unfortunately on Skylake this bottlenecks on the front-end at 4 uops / clock, taking at least 9/4 cycles to issue 1 iteration, not quite saturating the load ports.  Zen 2 or Ice Lake could sustain 2 loads per clock without any more unrolling or another level of `vorpd` combining.

---

**Another trick that might be possible is to use `vptest` or `vtestpd` on two vectors** to check that they're both non-zero.  But I'm not sure it's possible to correctly check that *every* element of both vectors is non-zero.  [Can PTEST be used to test if two registers are both zero or some other condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712243/can-ptest-be-used-to-test-if-two-registers-are-both-zero-or-some-other-condition) shows that the other way (that `_CMP_UNORD_Q` inputs are both all-zero) is not possible.

But this wouldn't really help: `vtestpd` / `jcc` is 3 uops total, vs. `vorpd` / `vmovmskpd` / `test+jcc` also being 3 fused-domain uops on existing Intel/AMD CPUs with AVX, so it's not even a win for throughput when you're branching on the result.  So even if it's possible, it's probably break even, although it might save a bit of code size.  And wouldn't be worth considering if it takes more than one branch to sort out the all-zeros or mix_zeros_and_ones cases from the all-ones case.

---

### Avoiding work: check `fenv` flags instead

If your array was the result of computation in this thread, just check the FP exception sticky flags (in MXCSR manually, or via `fenv.h` `fegetexcept`) to see if an FP "invalid" exception has happened since you last cleared FP exceptions.  If not, I think that means the FPU hasn't produced any NaN outputs and thus there are none in arrays written since then by this thread.

If it is set, you'll have to check; the invalid exception might have been raised for a temporary result that didn't propagate into this array.

---

### Cache blocking:

If/when fenv flags don't let you avoid the work entirely, or aren't a good strategy for your program, **try to fold this check into whatever produced the array, or into the next pass that reads it**.  So you're reusing data while it's already loaded into vector registers, increasing computational intensity.  (ALU work per load/store.)

Even if data is already hot in L1d, it will still bottleneck on load port bandwidth: 2 loads per `cmppd` still bottlenecks on 2/clock load port bandwidth, on CPUs with 2/clock `vcmppd ymm` (Skylake but not Haswell).

Also worthwhile to align your pointers to make sure you're getting full load throughput from L1d cache, especially if data is sometimes already hot in L1d.

Or at *least* **cache-block it** so you check a 128kiB block before running another loop on that same block while it's hot in cache.  That's half the size of 256k L2 so your data should still be hot from the previous pass, and/or hot for the next pass.

Definitely avoid running this over a whole multi-megabyte array and paying the cost of getting it into the CPU core from DRAM or L3 cache, then evicting again before another loop reads it.  That's worst case computational intensity, paying the cost of getting it into a CPU core's private cache more than once.

Comment: Perfect. I had to read through your answer a few times to try and take in all the useful tidbits. I had not thought about reprocessing the end of the array before. In similar code I added openmp and found no benefit when used with SIMD which after some number crunching I realized was because of the memory bandwidth limit.

Comment: @Jimbo: on "client" chips (desktop/laptop), a single core can nearly saturate memory bandwidth.  That's not the case on many-core Xeon chips: they have more total bandwidth and *lower* single-core bandwidth.  [Why is Skylake so much better than Broadwell-E for single-threaded memory throughput?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39260020).  Like I said, this check has very low computational intensity and should be folded into a different pass over the data, or at least cache-blocked so data is hot in L2 or L1d cache for this or the next pass.