# compare instruction not working correctly

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, masm32

I am comparing some input received from the user with some numbers, and the same jump is taken regardless of the compare.

User input is defined as so:

```
.data?
    userInput REAL4 ?
```

And when I compare it I use:

```
cmp userInput, 18200
jge _tb0    ;This jump is always taken
```

However I have tested with `userInput` being less than, equal, and great than `18200` but it still jumps to the same label.

I have just started learning assembly from [this](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/sigwin/old/workshops/winasmtut.pdf) tutorial, which has been great so far, but doesn't have a lot of information and I am having trouble finding a good, detailed tutorial online so that I can learn what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE:**

After reading a bit on using the FPU to do floating point math, I came up with the following code for variables:

```
.data?
    userInput real4 ?

.const
    tb0_max real4 18200.00
```

and the following code for comparing:

```
fld userInput
fcom tb0_max
jge _tb0
```

However I still get the same result as before, I jump to _tb0 regardless of the value given as user input

**UPDATE 2:**

After reading [this](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap7.htm#fcom) on comparing with the FPU, I came across the following code which **should**, according to the article, allow me to move the compare states from the FPU to the CPU so that I can use a regular CPU compare instruction:

```
fld userInput
fcom tb0_max
fstsw ax
fwait
sahf
jge _tb0
```

However I am still having the same issue, the compare always result as the userInput being less than the constant 18200.00 regardless of userInput

Comment: You might want to see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7057771/3857942) about floating point compare .

Comment: Look at the links at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for good reference material.  If you think the tutorial you found is worth adding to the tag wiki, go for it.  It's pretty light on good links for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

`cmp` itself works correctly. But you aren't using it correctly. `REAL4` is a floating point type. `cmp` works with integer operands only. Either use integers or learn how to compare floating point values.

Comment: I looked around on the internet and learnt a bit on comparing floating point values, but I still get the same result. Can you look at my update?

Comment: @Shadow Look closely at what flags `fcom` affects and what flags `jge` inspects. Are those the same flags, in the same register? Also look at `fcomi` in case your CPU supports it.

Comment: I read up on moving the FPU states to the CPU so that I can do a regular compare, but it still has the same result. Could you take a look at my second update? I included a link to the article I am using.

Comment: @Shadow jge jumps if (SF XOR OF) = 0. Why are you using it and ignoring what the article says about the comparison result appearing in ZF/PF/CF?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to compare your single precission float (*userInput*) with an integer (*18200*) you could just temporarily store it as an integer and then perform the comparison:

```
.data?
userInput   REAL4 ?
tempInteger dd ?

...

fld   userInput
fistp tempInteger
cmp   tempInteger, 18200
jge   _tb0
```