# Cube root on x87 FPU using Newton-Raphson method

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, newtons-method, x87

I am trying to write an assembly program using the 8086 processor that will find the cube root of a number. Obviously I am using floating points.

Algorithm based upon [Newton-Raphson method](http://www.mathpath.org/Algor/cuberoot/cube.root.newton.htm):

```
root := 1.0; 
repeat
     oldRoot := root;
     root := (2.0*root + x/(root*root)) / 3.0 
until ( |root – oldRoot| < 0.001;
```

**How do I divide (2*root + x) by (root*root)?**

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK 4096

.DATA
root    REAL4   1.0
oldRoot REAL4   2.0
Two     REAL4   2.0
inttwo  DWORD   2
itThree DWORD   3
three   REAL4   3.0
x       DOWRD   27


.CODE
main    PROC
        finit           ; initialize FPU
        fld     root    ; root in ST
        fmul    two     ; root*two
        fadd    x       ; root*two+27

        fld     root    ; root in ST
        fimul    root    ; root*root

        mov     eax, 0  ; exit
        ret
main    ENDP 
END
```

I guess I don't understand what is in the stack at what location. Does the product for line

> fimul    root    ; root*root

go into ST(1)? EDIT No, it goes into st(0) what was in st(0) got pushed down the stack to st(1)

But I haven't figured out the answer to my question... **How do I divide?** Now I see **I need to divide st(1) by st(0) but I don't know how.** I tried this.

```
finit           ; initialize FPU
fld     root    ; root in ST
fmul    two     ; root*two
fadd    xx      ; root*two+27
; the answer to root*two+x is stored in ST(0) when we load root st(0) moves to ST1 and we will use ST0 for the next operation

fld     root    ; root in ST previous content is now in ST1
fimul   root    ; root*root
fidiv   st(1)
```

EDIT:
I had the formula written wrong. This is what I am looking for.

```
(2.0*root) + x / (root*root)) / 3.0 That's what I need. 
STEP 1) (2 * root) 
STEP 2) x / (root * root) 
STEP 3) ADD step one and step 2 
STEP 4) divide step 3 by 3.0
```

root = (2.0*1.0) + 27/(1.0*1.0) / 3.0 ; (2) + 27/(1.0) / 3.0 = 11 ==> root = 11

EDIT2: NEW CODE!!

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK 4096

.DATA
root    REAL4   1.0
oldRoot REAL4   2.0
Two     REAL4   2.0
three   REAL4   3.0
xx      REAL4   27.0


.CODE
main    PROC
        finit           ; initialize FPU
                fld     root    ; root in ST    ; Pass 1 ST(0) has 1.0  
repreatAgain:
        ;fld    st(2)

        fmul    two     ; root*two      ; Pass 1 ST(0) has 2                                                                            Pass 2 ST(0) = 19.333333 st(1) = 3.0 st(2) = 29.0 st(3) = 1.0

        ; the answer to roor*two is stored in ST0 when we load rootSTO moves to ST1 and we will use ST0 for the next operation
        fld     root    ; root in ST(0) previous content is now in ST(1)      Pass 1 ST(0) has 1.0 ST(1) has 2.0                        Pass 2 st(
        fmul    st(0), st(0)    ; root*root                                 ; Pass 1 st(0) has 1.0 st(1) has 2.0
        fld     xx                                                          ; Pass 1 st(0) has 27.0 st(1) has 1.0 st(2) has 2.0
        fdiv    st(0), st(1) ; x / (root*root)  ; Pass 1: 27 / 1              Pass 1 st(0) has 27.0 st(1) has 2.0 st(2) has 2.0
        fadd    st(0), st(2) ; (2.0*root) + x / (root*root))                  Pass 1 st(0) has 29.0 st(1) has 1.0 st(2) has 2.0

        fld     three                                                       ; Pass 1 st(0) has 3.0 st(1) has 29.0 st(2) has 1.0 st(3) has 2.0

        fld     st(1)                                                       ; Pass 1 st(0) has 3.0 st(1) has 29.0 st(2) = 1.0 st(3) = 2.0
        fdiv    st(0), st(1) ; (2.0*root) + x / (root*root)) / 3.0            Pass 1 st(1) has 9.6666666666667



        jmp     repreatAgain
        mov     eax, 0  ; exit
        ret
main    ENDP 
END
```

Comment: Before i even look at the code, I'm a bit confused in the question. Part of your calculation is `root := (2.0*root + x/(root*root)) / 3.0` . Because of order of precedence of operators that is the same as `root := ((2.0*root) + (x/(root*root))) / 3.0` . So my question is this. are you _SURE_ you want to be dividing (2*root + x) by (root*root)? either the question is wrong, or the equation you are actually trying to solve doesn't match the question.

Comment: Other than Michael's comments, you are probably looking for the `fdivp` instruction.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks, now you have me confused. The book says (2.0*root + x/(root X root)). I assume I need to divide 2*root+x by root*root.

Comment: (2.0*root) + x / (root*root)) / 3.0 That's what I need. So you are correct. 
STEP 1) (2 * root)
STEP 2) x / (root * root)
STEP 3) ADD step one and step 2
STEP 4) divide step 3 by 3.0

Comment: root = (2.0*1.0) + 27/(1.0*1.0) / 3.0
    ; (2) + 27/(1.0) / 3.0 = 11 ==> root = 11

Comment: You can hoist a division out of the loop by doing `2.0 / 3.0` and `x/3.0` ahead of time.  This is worth it if you expect the loop to run more than one iteration on average.  Also, `fimul [root]` is a bug: `root` is in `REAL4` (32bit float) format, not integer.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I had already figured this out. And when I copied it from my white board to paper I wrote it wrong. ugh

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am not sure the answer  to your question. My teacher did mention the RPN calculator. I am assuming that's what it is because he said "If you've ever used an HP calculator with reverse Polish notation (RPN) then you're used to this idea. With these calculators, to add 4.3 and 5.6 you first enter 4.3 to the "stack", then you enter 5.6 to the "stack", then you hit the + key to add the two numbers and put the sum on the stack.". He doesn't really give lectures.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I got the loop body down to only two insns of overhead (`fld st(0)` and `fxch`) more than what's actually required for the computation.  I think I'm genetically incapable of looking at anything without wanting to optimize it, and it seemed a shame not to post the result.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: yeah, I agree.  Hopefully my optimized code is totally incomprehensible until @ GeekyDewd learns more x87, which is the ultimate goal.  @ Geeky, I'd recommend still implementing it all yourself, like Michael says.  I know all you were asking was how to `fdiv`.  My optimized version is there mostly because *I* was curious, not because I think it's going to help you very much!  If you learn anything useful from trying to understand it (successfully or not), then so much the better.  You might see code like that in compiler output.

Comment: I wasn't really paying much attention to your edit, but the steps to compute one iteration seemed okay, but the example seems wrong  `root = (2.0*1.0) + 27/(1.0*1.0) / 3.0 ; (2) + 27/(1.0) / 3.0 = 11 ==> root = 11`. I don't think your example is correct It should be ((2) + 27/(1.0)) / 3.0 = 9.6667 instead of 11? You divided 27 by 3 and added 2, but it should have been (2+27)/3.0 . The example would be expressed as `root = ((2.0*1.0) + 27/(1.0*1.0)) / 3.0 ; ((2) + 27/(1.0)) / 3.0 = 9.667 ==> root = 9.667`

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. the book had confusing parenthesis. I igonored them and followed OP and got 9.667. My code generates 9.667 for the first loop. but additional loops aren't working.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for the edit! I got the first loop working, I get 9.6667 in ST(0) but the next loops are a dud

Comment: @MichaelPetch I put it in the EDIT2 new code spot. I should have said I was going to do that. :)

Comment: tried changing *fdiv st(0), st(1) ; (2.0*root) + x / (root*root)) / 3.0* to *fdivp* It made it worse.

Comment: I may be reading it wrong, but you rely on memory address `root` also containing the value from the last pass, but I don't see you write the new root value back into your `root` memory variable at the bottom of your loop.

Comment: @GeekyDewd: I see your EDIT2 in the question with a big code dump, but there's no new question in the post, just a comment that "it doesn't work".  You should know by now that more specific problem statements are necessary to make good questions.  (Also, the question post is getting kind of bloated.  Consider trimming down the early bits that repeatedly just ask how to divide, since you're now asking for debugging help.)

Comment: @MichaelPetch's probably right, though: if you never `fst` to `root` at the end of an iteration, you can't usefully load from it in the next iteration.  I'd suggest designing your loop so it starts with `root` in `st(0)`, and ends with the next iteration's `root` value in `st(0)`.  Use `fld1` to load your initial 1.0 guess.

Comment: Seems this is turning into a new question. It appears you got your original answer about doing the calculation `root := (2.0*root + x/(root*root)) / 3.0`. Getting the loop going seems to be a separate problem that should probably be separated from this question.

Comment: What is 1#IND? It's popping up in my registers, it's pissing me off that the computer can't calculate.

Comment: updated my answer.  `1#IND` is probably what GDB prints for [the floating point indefinite value](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap2.htm#indefini).  It's one flavour of NaN that you get from invalid operations, including x87 stack overflow (which you code causes).  The register stack is a major annoyance, and a normal flat register set is one of the big advantages that SSE has over x87.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intel's insn reference manual documents all the instructions, including [`fdiv`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FDIV:FDIVP:FIDIV.html) and `fdivr` (x/y instead of y/x).  If you really need to learn mostly-obsolete x87 (`fdiv`) instead of SSE2 (`divss`), then [this x87 tutorial is essential reading](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html), esp. the early chapter that explains the register stack.  Also see [this x87 FP comparison Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057501/x86-assembler-floating-point-compare).  See more links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

---

re: EDIT2 code dump:

You have 4 `fld` instructions inside the loop, but no `p`-suffixed operations.  Your loop will overflow the 8-register FP stack on the 3rd iteration, at which point you'll get a NaN.  (specifically, the indefinite-value NaN, which printf prints as `1#IND`.

I'd suggest **designing your loop so an iteration starts with `root` in `st(0)`, and ends with the next iteration's `root` value in `st(0)`**.  Don't load or store to/from `root` inside the loop.  Use `fld1` to load 1.0 as your initial value outside the loop, and `fstp  [root]` after the loop to pop `st(0)` into memory.

---

You picked the most inconvenient way to do tmp / 3.0

```
                          ; stack = tmp   (and should otherwise be empty once you fix the rest of your code)
    fld     three         ; stack = 3.0, tmp
    fld     st(1)         ; stack = tmp, 3.0, tmp   ; should have used fxchg to just swap instead of making the stack deeper
    fdiv    st(0), st(1)  ; stack = tmp/3.0, 3.0, tmp
```

`fdiv`, `fsub`, etc. have multiple register-register forms: one where `st(0)` is the destination, and one where it's the source.  The form with `st(0)` as the source is also available with a `p`op, so you could

```
    fld     three         ; stack = 3.0, tmp
    fdivp                 ; stack = tmp / 3.0  popping the stack back to just one entry
    ; fdivp  st(1), st(0) ; this is what fdivp with no operands means
```

It's actually even simpler than that if you use a memory operand directly instead of loading it.  Since you want `st(0) /= 3.0`, **you can do `fdiv  [three]`**.  In that case, FP ops are just like integer ops, where you can do `div dword ptr [integer_from_memory]` to use a memory source operand.

The non-commutative operations (subtract and divide) also have reverse versions (e.g. `fdivr`), which can save you an `fxchg` or let you use a memory operand even if you'd needed 3.0/tmp instead of tmp/3.0

---

**Dividing by 3 is the same as multiplying by 1/3**, and `fmul` is much faster than `fdiv`.  From a code-simplicity point of view, multiply is commutative, so another way to implement `st(0) /= 3` is:

```
fld    [one_third]
fmulp                  ; shorthand for  fmulp st(1), st(0)

; or
fmul   [one_third]
```

Note that `1/3.0` has no exact representation in binary floating point, but all integers between +/- about 2^23 do (size of mantissa of single-precision REAL4).  You should only care about this if you were expecting to work with exact multiples of three.

---

#### Comments on the original code:

You can hoist a division out of the loop by doing `2.0 / 3.0` and `x/3.0` ahead of time.  This is worth it if you expect the loop to run more than one iteration on average.

---

You can duplicate the top of the stack with `fld st(0)`, so you don't have to keep loading from memory.

---

`fimul [root]` (**integer** mul) is a bug: Your `root` is in `REAL4` (32bit float) format, not integer.  `fidiv` is similarly a bug, and of course doesn't work with an x87 register as a source operand.

Since you have `root` at the top of the stack, I think you can just `fmul st(0)` to use `st(0)` as both the explicit and implicit operand, resulting in `st(0) = st(0) * st(0)`, with no change in the depth of the stack.

---

You could also use sqrt as **a better initial approximation** than 1.0, or maybe `+/-1 * sqrtf(fabsf(x))`.  I don't see an x87 instruction for applying the sign of one float to another, just `fchs` to unconditionally flip, and `fabs` to unconditionally clear the sign bit.  There is an `fcmov`, but it requires a P6 or later CPU.  You mentioned 8086, but then used `.586`, so IDK what you're targeting.

---

#### Better loop body:

Not debugged or tested, but your code full of repeated loads from the same data was making me crazy.  This optimized version is here because I was curious, not because I think it's going to help the OP directly.

Also, hopefully this is a good example of how to comment the data flow in code where it's tricky.  (e.g. x87, or vectorized code with shuffles).

```
## x/3.0 in st(1)
## 2.0/3.0 in st(2)

# before each iteration: st(0) = root
#  after each iteration: st(0) = root * 2.0/3.0 + (x/3.0 / (root*root)), with constants undisturbed

loop_body:
    fld     st(0)         ; stack: root, root, 2/3, x/3
    fmul    st(0), st(0)  ; stack: root^2, root, 2/3, x/3
    fdivr   st(0), st(3)  ; stack: x/3 / root^2, root, 2/3, x/3
    fxchg   st(1)         ; stack: root, x/3/root^2, 2/3, x/3
    fmul    st(0), st(2)  ; stack: root*2/3, x/3/root^2, 2/3, x/3
    faddp                 ; stack: root*2/3 + x/3/root^2, 2/3, x/3

; TODO: compare and loop back to loop_body

    fstp    [root]         ; store and pop
    fstp    st(0)          ; pop the two constants off the FP stack to empty it before returning
    fstp    st(0)
    ; finit is very slow, ~80cycles, don't use it if you don't have to.
```

32bit function calling-conventions return FP results in st(0), so you could do that, but then the caller probably have to store somewhere.

Comment: I'd also point out that dividing by three may be better expressed by multiplying with one third.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to answer this on a very basic level for those people new to x87 who may be faced with a calculation that needs to be done on the FPU.

There are two things to consider. If you are given a calculation ([*INFIX* notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation)) like:

```
root := (2.0*root + x/(root*root)) / 3.0
```

Is there a way to translate this into basic instructions that can be used by the x87 FPU? Yes, at a very basic level the x87 FPU is a stack that acts like a sophisticated [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) calculator. The equation in your code is *INFIX* notation. If you convert this to *POSTFIX*(RPN) notation, it can easily be implemented as a stack with operations.

This [document](http://csis.pace.edu/~wolf/CS122/infix-postfix.htm) provides some information on converting to *POSTFIX* notation. Following the rules your *POSTFIX* equivalent would look like:

```
2.0 root * x root root * / + 3.0 /
```

You could literally put that into an old RPN calculator (HPs) like the [HP 15C](http://hp15c.com/web/hp15c.html) using these keys where `root=1` and `x=27`:

```
2.0 [enter] root * x [enter] root [enter] root * / + 3.0 /
```

The online HP 15C should show the result of that calculation being 9.667. Translating this to basic x87:

- A number is a push to top of stack (fld)
- A variable is a push to top of stack (fld)
- `*` is fmulp (Multiply ST(1) by ST(0), store result in ST(1), and pop the register stack)
- `/` is fdivp (Divide ST(1) by ST(0), store result in ST(1), and pop the register stack)
- `+` is faddp (Add ST(0) to ST(1), store result in ST(1), and pop the register stack)
- `-` is fsubp (Subtract ST(0) from ST(1), store result in ST(1), and pop register stack)

You can literally convert `2.0 root * x root root * / + 3.0 /`  to x87 instructions:

```
fld Two      ; st(0)=2.0
fld root     ; st(0)=root, st(1)=2.0
fmulp        ; st(0)=(2.0 * root)
fld xx       ; st(0)=x, st(1)=(2.0 * root)
fld root     ; st(0)=root, st(1)=x, st(2)=(2.0 * root)
fld root     ; st(0)=root, st(1)=root, st(2)=x, st(3)=(2.0 * root)
fmulp        ; st(0)=(root * root), st(1)=x, st(2)=(2.0 * root)
fdivp        ; st(0)=(x / (root * root)), st(1)=(2.0 * root)
faddp        ; st(0)=(2.0 * root) + (x / (root * root))
fld Three    ; st(0)=3.0, st(1)=(2.0 * root) + (x / (root * root))
fdivp        ; st(0)=((2.0 * root) + (x / (root * root))) / 3.0
```

Once you have the basics, you can move on to improving efficiency.

---

### Regarding Edit 2 / Followup question

One thing to keep in mind is that if you don't use instructions that pop values off the stack, each iteration of the loop will consume more FPU stack slots. Generally the FPU instructions ending with **`P`** pop values off the stack. You don't use any instructions to remove items off the stack, the FPU stack keeps growing.

Unlike the program stack in user space, the FPU stack is very limited as it only has 8 slots. If you put more than 8 active values on the stack you will get overflow errors in the form of `1#IND`. If we analyze your code and view the stack after each instruction we'd find this:

```
    fld     root            ; st(0)=root  
repreatAgain:
    fmul    two             ; st(0)=(2.0*root)      
    fld     root            ; st(0)=root, st(1)=(2.0*root) 
    fmul    st(0), st(0)    ; st(0)=(root*root), st(1)=(2.0*root)
    fld     xx              ; st(0)=x, st(1)=(root*root), st(2)=(2.0*root)
    fdiv    st(0), st(1)    ; st(0)=(x/(root*root)), st(1)=(root*root), st(2)=(2.0*root)
    fadd    st(0), st(2)    ; st(0)=((2.0*root) + x/(root*root)), st(1)=(root*root), st(2)=(2.0*root)
    fld     three           ; st(0)=3.0, st(1)=((2.0*root) + x/(root*root)), st(2)=(root*root), st(3)=(2.0*root)                                            
    fld     st(1)           ; st(0)=((2.0*root) + x/(root*root)), st(1)=3.0, st(2)=((2.0*root) + x/(root*root)), st(3)=(root*root), st(4)=(2.0*root)
    fdiv    st(0), st(1)    ; st(0)=(((2.0*root) + x/(root*root))/3.0), st(1)=3.0, st(2)=((2.0*root) + x/(root*root)), st(3)=(root*root), st(4)=(2.0*root)
    jmp     repreatAgain
```

Observe that after the last *FDIV* instruction and before the *JMP* we have 5 items on the stack (*st(0)* through *st(4)*). When we entered the loop we only had 1 which was `root` in *st(0)*. The best way to resolve this is to use instructions in such a way that values get popped (removed) from the stack as the calculation progresses.

One other less efficient way is to free up the values we no longer want on the stack before repeating the loop. The [*FFREE*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FFREE.html) instruction can used for this purpose by manually marking the entries unused starting from the bottom of the stack. If you add these lines after the code above, and before the `jmp repreatAgain` the code should work:

```
ffree   st(4)           ; st(0)=(((2.0*root) + x/(root*root))/3.0), st(1)=3.0, st(2)=((2.0*root) + x/(root*root)), st(3)=(root*root)
ffree   st(3)           ; st(0)=(((2.0*root) + x/(root*root))/3.0), st(1)=3.0, st(2)=((2.0*root) + x/(root*root))
ffree   st(2)           ; st(0)=(((2.0*root) + x/(root*root))/3.0), st(1)=3.0
ffree   st(1)           ; st(0)=(((2.0*root) + x/(root*root))/3.0)
fst     root            ; Update root variable
jmp     repreatAgain
```

With the use of the *FFREE* instruction we end the loop with only the new `root` in *st(0)*.

I've also added `fst root` because of the way you did your calculation. Your calculation includes `fld root` which relies on the value in `root` being updated when each loop is finished. There is a more efficient way of doing this but I'm providing a fix that works in your current code without much reworking.

If you were to use the inefficient/simple code snippet I provided earlier to do the calculations you'd end up with code likes this:

```
    finit        ; initialize FPU
repreatAgain:
    fld Two      ; st(0)=2.0
    fld root     ; st(0)=root, st(1)=2.0
    fmulp        ; st(0)=(2.0 * root)
    fld xx       ; st(0)=x, st(1)=(2.0 * root)
    fld root     ; st(0)=root, st(1)=x, st(2)=(2.0 * root)
    fld root     ; st(0)=root, st(1)=root, st(2)=x, st(3)=(2.0 * root)
    fmulp        ; st(0)=(root * root), st(1)=x, st(2)=(2.0 * root)
    fdivp        ; st(0)=(x / (root * root)), st(1)=(2.0 * root)
    faddp        ; st(0)=(2.0 * root) + (x / (root * root))
    fld Three    ; st(0)=3.0, st(1)=(2.0 * root) + (x / (root * root))
    fdivp        ; newroot = st(0)=((2.0 * root) + (x / (root * root))) / 3.0
    fstp root    ; Store result at top of stack into root and pop value
                 ;     at this point the stack is clear again since
                 ;     all items pushed have been popped.

    jmp repreatAgain
```

This code doesn't require *FFREE* because elements are popped off the stack as the calculation progresses. The instruction *FADDP*, *FSUBP*, *FDIVP*, *FADDP* will additionally pop the value off the top of the stack. This has the side effect of keeping the stack clear of the partial intermediate calculations.

---

### Integrate a Loop

To integrate the loop into the simple/inefficient code I created earlier, you can use a variant of the [FCOM (Floating point compare)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FCOM:FCOMP:FCOMPP.html) for comparison. The results of the floating point compare is then transferred/converted to the regular CPU flags (EFLAGS). One can then use the regular comparison operators to perform the conditional checks. The code could look like this:

```
epsilon REAL4   0.001

.CODE
main PROC
    finit              ; initialize FPU

repeatAgain:
    fld Two            ; st(0)=2.0
    fld root           ; st(0)=root, st(1)=2.0
    fmulp              ; st(0)=(2.0 * root)
    fld xx             ; st(0)=x, st(1)=(2.0 * root)
    fld root           ; st(0)=root, st(1)=x, st(2)=(2.0 * root)
    fld root           ; st(0)=root, st(1)=root, st(2)=x, st(3)=(2.0 * root)
    fmulp              ; st(0)=(root * root), st(1)=x, st(2)=(2.0 * root)
    fdivp              ; st(0)=(x / (root * root)), st(1)=(2.0 * root)
    faddp              ; st(0)=(2.0 * root) + (x / (root * root))
    fld Three          ; st(0)=3.0, st(1)=(2.0 * root) + (x / (root * root))
    fdivp              ; newroot=st(0)=((2.0 * root) + (x / (root * root))) / 3.0
    fld root           ; st(0)=oldroot, st(1)=newroot
    fsub st(0), st(1)  ; st(0)=(oldroot-newroot), st(1)=newroot
    fabs               ; st(0)=(|oldroot-newroot|), st(1)=newroot
    fld epsilon        ; st(0)=0.001, st(1)=(|oldroot-newroot|), st(2)=newroot
    fcompp             ; Do compare&set x87 flags pop top two values off stack
                       ;     st(0)=newroot    
    fstsw ax           ; Copy x87 Status Word containing the result to AX
    fwait              ; Insure previous instruction completed
    sahf               ; Transfer condition codes to the CPU's flags register

    fstp root          ; Store result (newroot) at top of stack into root 
                       ;     and pop value. At this point the stack is clear
                       ;     again since all items pushed have been popped.
    jbe repeatAgain    ; If 0.001 <= (|oldroot-newroot|) repeat
    mov eax, 0         ; exit
    ret
main    ENDP 
END
```

Note: The usage of *FCOMPP* and manual transfer of x87 flags to CPU flags is driven by the fact that you have **.586** directive at the top of your code. I'm making the assumption that because you didn't specify **.686** or later that instructions like [*FCOMI*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FCOMI:FCOMIP:%20FUCOMI:FUCOMIP.html) are not available. If you were using `.686` or later, then the bottom part of the code could have looked like:

```
fld root           ; st(0)=oldroot, st(1)=newroot
fsub st(0), st(1)  ; st(0)=(oldroot-newroot), st(1)=newroot
fabs               ; st(0)=(|oldroot-newroot|), st(1)=newroot
fld epsilon        ; st(0)=0.001, st(1)=(|oldroot-newroot|), st(2)=newroot
fcomip st(0),st(1) ; Do compare & set CPU flags, pop one value off stack
                   ;     st(0)=(|oldroot-newroot|), st(1)=newroot
fstp st(0)         ; Pop temporary value off top of stack
                   ;     st(0)=newroot

fstp root          ; Store result (newroot) at top of stack into root 
                   ;     and pop value. At this point the stack is clear
                   ;     again since all items pushed have been popped.
jbe repeatAgain    ; If 0.001 <= (|oldroot-newroot|) repeat
```

---

### Quick method to creating RPN/Postfix from Infix notation

If learning to convert *Infix* notation to *RPN/Postfix* seems a bit daunting from the document I linked earlier in my question there is some relief. There are a number of websites that will do this work for you. One such site is [MathBlog](http://www.mathblog.dk/tools/infix-postfix-converter/). Just enter your equation, click convert and it should show you the *RPN/Postfix* equivalent. It is limited to +-/*, parentheses and exponents with ^.

---

### Optimizations

A big key to optimizing the code is to optimize the formula by separating the parts that remain constant between each loop from the parts that are variable. The constant parts can be computed before the loop begins.

Your original equation is this:

[image: Original Equation]

Separating the constants part we can arrive at:

[image: Separate Constants]

If we replace the constants with identifiers where `twothirds` = 2.0/3.0, and `xover3` = x/3 then we end up with a simplified equation that looks like this:

[image: Final equation]

If we convert that to *POSTFIX/RPN* then we get:

```
twothirds root * xover3 root root * / +
```

A similar optimization is what Peter is taking advantage of in his answer under the section *Better loop body*. He places the constants `Twothirds` and `Xover3` onto the x87 FPU stack outside the loop, and references them as needed inside the loop. This avoids having to reread them unnecessarily from memory each time through the loop.

A more complete example based upon the optimization above:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK 4096

.DATA
xx        REAL4   27.0
root      REAL4   1.0
Three     REAL4   3.0
epsilon   REAL4   0.001
Twothirds REAL4 0.6666666666666666

.CODE
main PROC
    finit               ; Initialize FPU
    fld epsilon         ; st(0)=epsilon
    fld root            ; st(0)=prevroot (Copy of root), st(1)=epsilon
    fld TwoThirds       ; st(0)=(2/3), st(1)=prevroot, st(2)=epsilon 
    fld xx              ; st(0)=x, st(1)=(2/3), st(2)=prevroot, st(3)=epsilon
    fdiv Three          ; st(0)=(x/3), st(1)=(2/3), st(2)=prevroot, st(3)=epsilon
    fld st(2)           ; st(0)=root, st(1)=(x/3), st(2)=(2/3), st(3)=prevroot, st(4)=epsilon

repeatAgain:

    ; twothirds root * xover3 root root * / +
    fld st(0)           ; st(0)=root, st(1)=root, st(2)=(x/3), st(3)=(2/3), st(4)=prevroot, st(5)=epsilon
    fmul st(0), st(3)   ; st(0)=(2/3*root), st(1)=root, st(2)=(x/3), st(3)=(2/3), st(4)=prevroot, st(5)=epsilon           
    fxch                ; st(0)=root, st(1)=(2/3*root), st(2)=(x/3), st(3)=(2/3), st(4)=prevroot, st(5)=epsilon
    fmul st(0), st(0)   ; st(0)=(root*root), st(1)=(2/3*root), st(2)=(x/3), st(3)=(2/3), st(4)=prevroot, st(5)=epsilon
    fdivr st(0), st(2)  ; st(0)=((x/3)/(root*root)), st(1)=(2/3*root), st(2)=(x/3), st(3)=(2/3), st(4)=prevroot, st(5)=epsilon
    faddp               ; st(0)=((2/3*root)+(x/3)/(root*root)), st(1)=(x/3), st(2)=(2/3), st(3)=prevroot, st(4)=epsilon
    fxch st(3)          ; st(0)=prevroot, st(1)=(x/3), st(2)=(2/3), newroot=st(3)=((2/3*root)+(x/3)/(root*root)), st(4)=epsilon 
    fsub st(0), st(3)   ; st(0)=(prevroot-newroot), st(1)=(x/3), st(2)=(2/3), st(3)=newroot, st(4)=epsilon
    fabs                ; st(0)=(|prevroot-newroot|), st(1)=(x/3), st(2)=(2/3), st(3)=newroot, st(4)=epsilon
    fld st(4)           ; st(0)=0.001, st(1)=(|prevroot-newroot|), st(2)=(x/3), st(3)=(2/3), st(4)=newroot, st(5)=epsilon

    fcompp              ; Do compare&set x87 flags pop top two values off stack
                        ;     st(0)=(x/3), st(1)=(2/3), st(2)=newroot, st(3)=epsilon    
    fstsw ax            ; Copy x87 Status Word containing the result to AX
    fwait               ; Insure previous instruction completed
    sahf                ; Transfer condition codes to the CPU's flags register

    fld st(2)           ; st(0)=newroot, st(1)=(x/3), st(2)=(2/3), st(3)=newroot, st(4)=epsilon
    jbe repeatAgain     ; If 0.001 <= (|oldroot-newroot|) repeat

    ; Remove temporary values on stack, cubed root in st(0)
    ffree st(4)         ; st(0)=newroot, st(1)=(x/3), st(2)=(2/3), st(3)=epsilon
    ffree st(3)         ; st(0)=newroot, st(1)=(x/3), st(2)=(2/3)
    ffree st(2)         ; st(0)=newroot, st(1)=(x/3)
    ffree st(1)         ; st(0)=newroot

    mov     eax, 0  ; exit
    ret
main ENDP 

END
```

This code places these values on the stack prior to entering the loop:

- st(4) = `Epsilon` value (0.001)
- st(3) = A copy of `root` before calculations are done (effectively `prevroot`)
- st(2) = The constant `Twothirds` (2/3)
- st(1) = `Xover3` (x/3)
- st(0) = Active copy of `root`

Before the loop repeats, the stack will have the layout above.

The code at the end before exiting removes all the temporary values and simply leaves the stack with the value of `root` on the top in *st(0)*.

Comment: `fmulP` is not available with a memory operand.  `fmulp` pops two stack regs and pushes the result.  `fmul` pops st(0) and pushes the result.

Comment: @PeterCordes lol, I temporarily deleted the question while I edited the question. I see you must have commented before my deletion. I ripped out (as I had typed it off the top of my head, and then realized needs some reworking for the reason you gave).

Comment: And I have chosen to keep the  simple reduced form out until i think of a good way to really explain it to a layman. Sometimes less is more, and I'll take the somewhat safer approach by keeping it as basic as possible.

Comment: 1#IND happens on about the 6th loop in st(0)

Comment: Wow, you really went nuts with this x87 tutorial.  I hadn't understood what `ffree` was for until seeing your example.  It's interesting that the freed register keeps its place in the revolving stack, though.  After freeing one register in the middle of the stack, and repeatedly running `fld1`, you can get 1,1,nan,nan,1,nan,nan (results in st(0) in that order, i.e. the resulting stack in reverse order).