# Reset variable assembly

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86

How do I reset a Real4 variable back to it's original state? I have `Value Real4 ?` in my data section and I performed an FADD operation and stored the result like so `FST Value`. I want to use Value again for something else, how do I reset Value?

Comment: Add a new temporary variable in your data section, and copy the value to the temporary variable. Never overwrite the original value.

Comment: Or undo the addition, but that's silly :)

Comment: @Jester Unfortunately due to round-off error, floating-point addition and subtraction will not necessarily restore the original number. As an artificial example, [(2 + 1000000) − 1000000] = [1000000 − 1000000] = 0.

Comment: @Nayuki lucky that I didn't say undo it with the subtraction of the same amount :D

Comment: @Jester I am curious, how else can you undo the addition?

Comment: @Nayuki Thank you- I did that and it worked. My instructor mentioned efficiency so I was afraid of adding more variables. I thought there was another way to reset a variable without adding more variables.

Comment: Load your value from memory onto the FPU stack, then make a copy of it on the FPU stack.

Comment: @YumeiiChii For most tasks in computer programming, the first priority is to write correct working code. Only after that is done, would we consider the question of efficiency. =)

Comment: @Nayuki ; I pretty much said the same thing recently in an x87 question PeterCordes and I wrote about: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36926441/3857942 .I think understanding the FPU stack, and getting working code going should be the first priority. once that is done then work on the efficiencies.

Comment: Store the result somewhere else?