# MASM assembly _ compare real numbers

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, masm, masm32

*I'm trying to compare a real number with a number but it doesn't work, what are the correct instructions for the following?

```
number_check:

     mov esi, input("Enter number (",60,"10): ");

     INVOKE StrToFloat, esi, ADDR num

     cmp num,10

     jge number_check
```

Comment: Integer `cmp` is certainly not what you want; FP uses different instructions, like `comiss` (and they don't take immediate operands).  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/comiss.  (Or for legacy x87, fcomi on P6-compatible CPUs).  You haven't said what your `StrToFloat` function does, but I assume stores a 32-bit float into memory at the address passed in the last arg?  Instead of returning a return value.  Maybe the return value is for an error status?

Comment: [How to compare 2 float in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5944185) shows how to use `fcom` + `fstsw ax` / `sahf`.  If you don't want to use obsolete stuff, `comiss` sets EFLAGS in an equivalent way.